# Lightroom: Is there a way to zoom in and crop all images?

Tags: lightroom

Can I achieve this only using Lightroom?:

I have several hundred images I want to zoom into and crop.
I want to just crop into the centre area of each photo, for all images. (I may also need to move the crop about on a few). Then, I will export and to send to client.

I realise, I could probably export all images from Lightroom to then get the job done in Photoshop with 'Batch', but is there a way to do it in Lightroom?

I have been using Lightroom for a while. I know how to copy the dimensions to be the same for all images, but not to zoom/crop into the image.

Answer (score 2):

This is literally the kind of thing LR was made for. If you just select all images in the film strip at the bottom and then crop, using the crop and straighten tool (intuitive shortcut R), the currently displayed one, this will be applied to all of them.

If you need to move the crop after drawing it, you'll have to select them individually or in groups, as convenient, of course.

Comment: Thank you. That didn't quite work, so after cropping the first one, I copied the Crop setting and pasted them to the others, and that worked. Cheers!